# Random variable in an input function

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple Python program asking the user the result of a random addition. The program crashes on the 8th line. Is it not allowed to refer to a random variable in Python?

```
#prompts random addition
import random
r1 = random.randint(0, 10)
r2 = random.randint(0, 10)
result = r1+r2

while True:
    answer = int(input('What is',r1, '+', r2))

    if answer != result:
        print("Wrong, try again.")
    else:
        print("correct!")
        break;
```

The message shown when it crashes is below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenjin/Desktop/Module4.py", line 89, in 
    answer = input('What is',r1, '+', r2)
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 4

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? The biggest problem I see is that you are trying to compare `answer` (a `str` value) to a `int` value (`result`), which always compare as not equal.

Comment: `input` doesn't take multiple arguments; it takes a single string (which at least one answer pointed out, but was deleted before I could retract my mistaken downvote).

Answer (score 2):

[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) takes an (optional) argument, you are passing 4 arguments to it. You need to build a string to pass to it. Example:

```
answer = input(f'What is {r1} + {r2}? ')
```

Comment: does the input function only take string arguments?

Comment: no, it can take integers, lists, custom objects, etc, but only one (or zero).